# How to retrieve the A1-style reference of an Excel worksheet cell in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

How do I retrieve the A1-style reference of an Excel worksheet cell in VBA? I'm using Access 2007 VBA.

So where for example for the cell `MyWorksheet.Range("A1").Offset(2, 3)` the value "D3" is returned.

It seems such a simple question.

Comment: In answer to your flag, please see "What does deletion mean for a post?" in [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean).

Comment: Okay, thanks, now it's clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyWorksheet.Range("A1").Offset(2,3).Address(False,False)
```

The arguments (all optional) for address are

RowAboslute - False for no dollars signs

ColumnAbsolute - False for no dollar signs

ReferenceStyle - default is xlA1 (constant value is 1 if your late binding)

External - include the workbook/worksheet name

RelativeTo - This one's a complete mystery to me.  It never works how I expect.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of Relative when working in VBA is to (mentally) convert everything to R1C1 mode, work out the reference relative to the given anchor point, then convert the result back to A1 mode.

Answer (score 1):

To print the A1 style address to the Immediate Window, use the following. By specifying that you don't want the columns or rows to be absolute, you don't have to use the replace function.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Range("A1").Offset(2, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
End Sub
```